# How can i remove a specific part of a variable value using perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix

we have a variable values 
value is : /abc/cde/efg/sanj/Sent//abc/cde/efg/sanj/sample sample1.pdf

I want to remove the middle part of this value '/abc/cde/efg/sanj/'.
Is it possible to remove this part.

Comment: In this variable we found double `forward slash //`? sent is the keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're talking paths,

```perl
use Path::Tiny qw( path );

my $qfn = '/abc/cde/efg/sanj/Sent//abc/cde/efg/sanj/sample sample1.pdf';
my $base_qfn = '/abc/cde/efg/sanj';

say path($qfn)->relative($base_qfn);
```

Output:

```
Sent/abc/cde/efg/sanj/sample sample1.pdf
```